# How to handle incomplete Stripe Onboarding of Express Connected Account

Tags: stripe-payments, registration

I am trying to enable users to my platform to create an Express Account with Stripe Connect.  Here is my code:

```
 function account() {

            $profiledata["accountLink"] = "";
            $chargesEnabled = "";
            $email = $this->session->userdata('email');

            $this->load->model("Profiles_model");
            $accID = $this->Profiles_model->fetch_stripe_account($email);

            // check user's account - charges_enabled
            if ($accID != "") {
                $userAccount = $this->stripe_lib->accountRetrieve($accID);
                $chargesEnabled = $userAccount->charges_enabled;

                // create login link to Stripe express account
                $loginStripeLink = $this->stripe_lib->createLoginLink($accID);
                $profiledata["loginLink"] = $loginStripeLink->url;

            } else {
                // Load Stripe library & product model
                $this->load->library('stripe_lib');
                $this->load->model('products_model');

                // get onboarding link
                $account = $this->stripe_lib->createExpressAccount();
                $accountLink = $this->stripe_lib->createAccountLink($account->id);
                $profiledata["accountLink"] = $accountLink->url;
                $this->Profiles_model->insert_stripe_account($account->id, $email);
            }

            // get balance
            $balAmount = "";
            $balCurrency = "";
            $balance = $this->stripe_lib->accountBalance($accID);
            if ($balance) {
                $balAmount = $balance->instant_available[0]->amount/100;
                $balCurrency = $balance->instant_available[0]->currency;
            }
            $profiledata["balanceAmount"] = $balAmount;
            $profiledata["balanceCurrency"] = $balCurrency;
            
            $profiledata["accID"] = $accID;
            $profiledata["chargesEnabled"] = $chargesEnabled;
            $profiledata["fetch_privateareamemberprofiledata"] = $this->Profiles_model->fetch_privateareamemberprofiledata();
            $profiledata["fetch_subscribedprofiledata"] = $this->Profiles_model->fetch_subscribedprofiledata();  //added
            $this->load->view('templates/header_pa');
            $this->load->view('pages/page-account', $profiledata);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer_pa');
        }
```

Now provided the person registering with Stripe provides their email and phone number, and validates thier phone number - it all works fine.  The problem can arise if the user aborts the Stripe on boarding process before doing that.  In this scenario, their Stripe Account number is still generated and stored on my system - but Stripe doesn't do the same.  Hence when they come back to try and onboard again, it throws an error.  Any ideas?  I was thinking there would be a webhook to use to enter in their Stripe Account Number on my system, but there isnt.

Answer (score 1):

Until the account has finished onboard, you'd need to send them back to Onboarding by creating another Account Link.

The problem doesn't appear to be as you describe -- your logic in your code looks to be:

```
if ( has account is) then (send to login link)
else ( create account and account link to send to onboarding)
```

This misses the case where an existing account still needs to continue onboarding.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#handle-users-not-completed-onboarding

> Retrieve the user’s account and check for charges_enabled. ... You can check the state of the details_submitted parameter on their account to see if they’ve completed the onboarding process.